# JS module pattern override function

Tags: javascript, module-pattern

I have following pattern

```
BASE = function () {
    var that = {};
    var number = 10;

    that.showNumber = function(){
        that.alertNumber();
    }

    that.alertNumber = function () {
        alert(number);
    };    
    return that;
};

CHILD = function () {
    var that = Object.create(BASE());
    var secondNumber = 20;

    // Override base function
    that.alertNumber = function () {
        alert(secondNumber);
    };
    return that;
};

var ch = CHILD();
ch.showNumber();
```

Can you tell me how can I adjust my module pattern inspired by Douglas CrockFord to fully override `alerNumber` function? So far `showNumber` function displays 10 instead of 20.

Thank you all in advanced

JSFiddle with code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xmBPw/)

Comment: Why not simply use prototype ? This would make it simple.

Comment: Why not write var that = new BASE(); ?

Comment: This pattern allows multiple inheritance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change

```
that.showNumber = function(){
    that.alertNumber();
}
```

to

```
that.showNumber = function(){
    this.alertNumber();
}
```

But I'm not sure I see why you don't simply use [the prototype-base inheritance model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Comment: That's the thing that I do not fully understand. Why `this.alertNumber()` in base is referenced to `that` in `Base` class?

Comment: This pattern you use sets a `that` variable in the closure to get sure the function showNumber is using the instance defined in the constructor, thus making most advanced inheritance schemes not working (for example a superclass function calling another function and letting it be overridden).

Comment: OK so if I get it well, when I want to be able to override parent function I have to use different pattern? I am sorry for such a noobish questions, but I have experience only with Java where inheritance is totally different.

Comment: Well, this pattern lets you override parent function, it just doesn't let you, if you're using `that`, call the child function from the parent. I'd suggest to use the standard pattern (see the link in my answer) as long as you aren't used to JavaScript (then you'll maybe use your own, which isn't so rare). And don't use "classes" when you don't need them. If your JS looks like Java, you're doing it wrong. You should have many functions and callbacks and not a lot of classes, even in a big application.

Comment: What I did not understand from your link how can I "hide" private variables and use them in public functions see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbn97/)